# How can check number in string?

Tags: python

I want to know that 'password' is containd number using 'string.digits'

```
import string

def validate_password(password):

    is_long = len(password)
    if is_long < 8:
        return False
      
    includes_digit = password
    for digit in string.digits:
        if digit in includes_digit:
            break
            return False
    
    
    for u in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if u in includes_digit:
            break
            return False
    
    
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if char in password:
            break
            return False
            
    return True

is_password_valid = validate_password("12345678ff")
print(is_password_valid)
```

I guess that is ok but didn't work
help me plz

Comment: In loop body, there is a break before the return stmt so return False stmt is never called.

Comment: Hi, your question isn't clear. What is a `containd` number? What is the error you are getting with the above code snippet. May be an example might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of your validators, you don't return `False` because that `return` statement is underneath the `if` statement. You always break before reaching the `return`.

Put an `else` under your `for` loops like this. This part executes if the `for` loop finishes without encountering a break.

```
includes_digit = password
for digit in string.digits:
    if digit in includes_digit:
        break
else:
    return False
```

Comment: omg, I didn't know that 'for-else ' Thank you so much

Comment: It's a great feature that you don't see used very much! Let me know if you have any problems with this solution. As a side note, regex is also really good for this, as @rubenpoppe suggested. If you're doing lots of validation of strings, I would definitely suggest using their solution and learning all about regex. It's a little tricky to begin with but very very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex in this case.

```py
import re

password = 'Azerty123'
contains_digit = bool(re.search('\d', password))
print(contains_digit) # True
```